# JQuery: Add a style to Regex-matches

Tags: jquery, regex, replace, highlight

I want to show HTML-Code as text in my website. I have following sample-text in my html:

```
<div id="test">
    &lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;  <br />
    &lt;p&gt;Hello2&lt;/p&gt;
</div>
```

which shows:

```
<p>Hello</p> 
<p>Hello2</p>
```

on my website.

Now I want to change the color of the tags. I found the idea on the internet of replacing a RegExp with the same text wrapped in a span with a class to change the style of that span.

I tried following in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var oldHtml = $("#test").html();
    var newHtml = oldHtml.replace(new RegExp("(&lt;){1}.*(&gt){1};","g"), "<span class='highlight'>$1</span>");
    $("#test").html(newHtml);
});
```

And got the following:

```
< 
<
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably will be better off putting your code in a `pre` or similar and using a library for syntax highlighting. Rolling your own is going to be a lot of work. Look at SO does it for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capture groups are in the wrong place. You are capturing the opening bracket into `$1` and the closi closing bracket into `$2`, which you never use.

> ```
> (&lt;){1}.*(&gt){1};
> ```

You also don't need the quantifier.

```
&lt;(.*?)&gt;
```

With this pattern and the same substitution it should work. The `*?` quantifier makes it not greedy, so it stops as early as possible with the match for anything.

Note that parsing HTML with regex is a bad idea. Even if parts of the HTML is escaped, it's still a hard language that is not regular. It's eventually not going to work. Use a parser instead. Or for your usecase, just use one of many easy to find and use syntax highlighting libraries.

Comment: I wrot this from my phone. The pattern might contain typing errors.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer. I'm using a syntax highlighting library now :)